# How to call UItableview Delegate methods. When tableview is in "for" Loop?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

// i am creating tableview in **for loop**. after looping once, tableview delegate/datasource methods needs to call. But here methods(delegate/datasource) are calling after finishing loop

> //**Note**: i am displaying all tables in scrollview based on page
>   controller

// here is my code

```
for(int i=0; i < 10; i++)
{
table_obj[i] = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 700, 500)];
            table_obj[i].separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
            table_obj[i].separatorColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            table_obj[i].delegate = self;
            table_obj[i].dataSource = self;
            table_obj[i].backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            [scrollview addSubview:table_obj[i]];

            [table_obj[i] reloadData];
}
```

//data is loading only in 10th table. not in all tables

Comment: Thats because when you set the dataSource to self, it gets overriden and will have the last one in the array as the current dataSource.

Comment: so what is the solution for this?

Comment: i am reloading table in for loop. at that time Delegates are calling, but data is not loading. data is loading only in last table

Comment: I understand that. The reason why this is happening is that when the delegate calls back, it will refer to the last tableView only because when setting the delegates, they get overriden. Check the answers below, they should be able to help you solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are reloading your table after that, then it should work fine.

I think the views that your are adding in that, rather than adding that in your - `(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`
 mehod, try using custom cell concept. and reload your table whenever you are going from one table view to another tableview.

[Custom cell tutorial.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html)

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use tag(`table_obj[i] = i`) to judge the delegate is invocated by which tableView.

for example :

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
        switch (tableView.tag) {
        case 0:
            //do something
            break;
        case 1:
            //do something
        break;

        ... ...

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Thats because when you set the delegate/dataSource to self, in the loop it gets overriden and will have the last one in the array as the current delegate/dataSource.

You can set 'tags' in your tableViews and then in the callbacks do manipulation based on the tag of the tableView.

Another option will be to loop through the array of tableViews to get the current one, but that isnt very efficient, so I believe the first option is better.