# How to set Data to multiple tableviews in for loop

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

i am creating tableview in for loop. after looping once, tableview delegate/datasource methods needs to call. But here methods(delegate/datasource) are calling after finishing loop, how to load data in tableviews

i am displaying tables in scrollview based page controller

```
for(int i=0; i < 10; i++)
{
table_obj[i] = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 700, 500)];
            table_obj[i].separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
            table_obj[i].separatorColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            table_obj[i].delegate = self;
            table_obj[i].dataSource = self;
            table_obj[i].backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            [scrollview addSubview:table_obj[i]];

            [table_obj[i] reloadData];
}
```

same question i found here [How to call UItableview Delegate methods. When tableview is in "for" Loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15523214/how-to-call-uitableview-delegate-methods-when-tableview-is-in-for-loop)  but it is not working for my side

Comment: post the code to help us understand your issue

Comment: you are add tableview inside scrollview  may problem is that when you are trying to click on tableview it will detect the scrollview touch so there is conflict between UItableview and scrollview touch.

Comment: @pradip rathod  i think  this only one way to get page controller in single view

Comment: [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/PageControl/Listings/PageControl_ViewController_swift.html)

Comment: @Nagendar can use collection view. table view inside collection view cell.and make the collection view scroll horizontal or vertical according to need.enable the paging inside collection view.on didscroll method change the pagecontroller indicator.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confused with multiple `TableView` object in a single class but with the availability of one `delegate` and `dataSource` methods.

Thats how you can implement delegate of multiple `tableViews` using single delegations.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (tableView == table_obj[0]) {
        //This method is invoked by the tableview available at index 0 in table_obj array.
        //return number of cells you want to show in this tableView
        return 5;

    }else if (tableView == table_obj[1]) {
        //This method is invoked by the tableview available at index 1 in table_obj array.
        //return number of cells you want to show in this tableView
        return 10;
    }else if (tableView == table_obj[2]) {
        //This method is invoked by the tableview available at index 2 in table_obj array.
        //return number of cells you want to show in this tableView
        return 15;
    }else {
        //if doesn't match with any tableView in array then just return 0
        return 0;
    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    if (tableView == table_obj[0]) {
        //This method is invoked by the tableview available at index 0 in table_obj array.
        //create cells for this tableView and set Data
        UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] init];
        return cell;

    }else if (tableView == table_obj[1]) {
        //This method is invoked by the tableview available at index 1 in table_obj array.
        //create cells for this tableView and set Data
        UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] init];
        return cell;
    }else if (tableView == table_obj[2]) {
        //This method is invoked by the tableview available at index 2 in table_obj array.
        //create cells for this tableView and set Data
        UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] init];
        return cell;
    }else {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] init];
        return cell;
    }

}
```

Comment: if we know the tableviews Count we can handle this way , in my side table count is coming from REST API

Comment: You mean you do not know the count of table view as well?

Comment: yeah i don't no count

Comment: You need to make your own delegate methods which returns you that which tableView is currently being display and the give you the index number of that tableView from array after that you can easily implement it.